# Issues multi-trackers and opencv's version

Tags: python, macos, opencv, pycharm

I'm trying to implement the OpenCV's multi-tracker as explained in this tutorial (https://www.learnopencv.com/multitracker-multiple-object-tracking-using-opencv-c-python/) but I'm facing some issues with the version of OpenCV.
As told in other answers on SO, for the single and multi tracker constructors I have to use opencv-contrib; however, once installed opencv-contrib in place of opencv, I'm able no more to use the VideoCapture function. I'm in a deadlock since I need both functions but contrib-opencv and opencv seem cannot co-exist in the same interpreter.
Has anyone faced the same issue and can help me with this?

```
    import sys
    import cv2
    from random import randint

    trackerTypes = ['BOOSTING', 'MIL', 'KCF', 'TLD', 'MEDIANFLOW', 'GOTURN', 'MOSSE', 'CSRT']


    def createTrackerByName(trackerType):
        # Create a tracker based on tracker name
        if trackerType == trackerTypes[0]:
            tracker = cv2.TrackerBoosting_create()
        elif trackerType == trackerTypes[1]:
            tracker = cv2.TrackerMIL_create()
        elif trackerType == trackerTypes[2]:
            tracker = cv2.TrackerKCF_create()
        elif trackerType == trackerTypes[3]:
            tracker = cv2.TrackerTLD_create()
        elif trackerType == trackerTypes[4]:
            tracker = cv2.TrackerMedianFlow_create()
        elif trackerType == trackerTypes[5]:
            tracker = cv2.TrackerGOTURN_create()
        elif trackerType == trackerTypes[6]:
            tracker = cv2.TrackerMOSSE_create()
        elif trackerType == trackerTypes[7]:
            tracker = cv2.TrackerCSRT_create()
        else:
            tracker = None
            print('Incorrect tracker name')
            print('Available trackers are:')
            for t in trackerTypes:
                print(t)

        return tracker


    def main():
        # Set video to load
        videoPath = "../../data/videos/case-1-2D.avi"

        # Create a video capture object to read videos
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(videoPath)

        # Read first frame
        success, frame = cap.read()
        # quit if unable to read the video file
        if not success:
            print('Failed to read video')
            sys.exit(1)

        ## Select boxes
    bboxes = []
    colors = []

    while True:
        bbox = cv2.selectROI('MultiTracker', frame)
        bboxes.append(bbox)
        colors.append((randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255)))
        print("Press q to quit selecting boxes and start tracking")
        print("Press any other key to select next object")
        k = cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF
        if (k == 113):  # q is pressed
            break

    print('Selected bounding boxes {}'.format(bboxes))

    # Specify the tracker type
    trackerType = "CSRT"

    # Create MultiTracker object
    multiTracker = cv2.MultiTracker_create()

    # Initialize MultiTracker
    for bbox in bboxes:
        multiTracker.add(createTrackerByName(trackerType), frame, bbox)

    # Process video and track objects
    while cap.isOpened():
        success, frame = cap.read()
        if not success:
            break

        # get updated location of objects in subsequent frames
        success, boxes = multiTracker.update(frame)

        # draw tracked objects
        for i, newbox in enumerate(boxes):
            p1 = (int(newbox[0]), int(newbox[1]))
            p2 = (int(newbox[0] + newbox[2]), int(newbox[1] + newbox[3]))
            cv2.rectangle(frame, p1, p2, colors[i], 2, 1)

        # show frame
        cv2.imshow('MultiTracker', frame)

        # quit on ESC button
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == 27:  # Esc pressed
            break



    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

If I use opencv-python package I get the error:

```
AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 
'MultiTracker_create'
```

If I use opencv-contrib-python package I get the error:

```
AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 
'VideoCapture'
```

If it can help, I'm working with PyCharm on MacOS using a VirtualEnv for my Python interpreter.
I already tried to installed opencv-contrib (alone), opencv (alone), keep both opencv-contrib and opencv on my interpreter, downgrade opencv to an early version that should support the functions I need (opencv 3.4).

Comment: "I'm able no more to use the VideoCapture function" what do you mean you're no longer able to use it? Please show us the exact way you are executing your Python script, and show us the exact error message you're getting. Make the Python script as minimal as possible---just enough code to reproduce your error and nothing more. FYI you should only use one or the other PyPI package---either `opencv-contrib-python` or `opencv-python`.

Comment: I just edit my question with code. I know opencv-contrib-python and opencv-python cannot co-exist, I use only one of them, I installed both together just as the last attempt.

Comment: Oh that indeed is quite weird. Let's start fresh to make sure there wasn't something weird that got broken in your env. Make a new Python venv, and install the latest `opencv-contrib-python` into it after activating it. Verify it is installed in your venv with `pip freeze` and check for it. If all is well, enter a Python interpreter and check `import cv2; hasattr(cv2, 'VideoCapture')`.

Comment: I made it run installing ```opencv-contrib-python``` in the MacOS's Python3 interpreter. Probably something broke in my VEnv as you suggested. Thank you for the help.